# Skip a div class with in a div web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website and my sample html looks like below

```
<div class="ism-true"><!-- message -->
                    <div id="post_message_5437898" data-spx-slot="1">

                        OK, although it's been several weeks since I installed the 

    <div><label>Quote:</label></div>
    <div class="panel alt2" style="border:1px inset">

        <div>
            Originally Posted by <strong>DeltaNu1142</strong>
        </div>
        <div style="font-style:italic">The very first thing I did </div>

    </div>
</div>When I got my grille back from the paint shop, I went to work on the
                    </div>
                    <!-- / message --></div>

<div class="ism-true"><!-- message -->
                    <div id="post_message_5125716">

                        <div style="margin:1rem; margin-top:0.3rem;">
    <div><label>Quote:</label></div>
    <div class="panel alt2" style="border:1px inset">

        <div>
            Originally Posted by <strong>HCFX2013</strong>
        </div>
        <div style="font-style:italic">I must be the minority that absolutely can't .</div>

    </div>
</div>Hello World.
                    </div>
                    <!-- / message --></div>
```

I want text which is only in post message class but not in "panel alt2" class. The position of class within "div id="post_message_" keeps changing. How can I ignore the text with in the panel alt2 class.

My code.

```
text = []
for item in soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"ism-true"}):
    result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
    div = item.find('div', class_="panel alt2")
    if div :
        result[0] = ' '.join(result[0].split(div.text.split()[-1])[1:])
        text.append(result[0])
    else:
        text.append(result)
```

The above code only gives me text when "Panel alt2" is first class within in div class. It doesnot hold good if position of class changes and throwing me error as "List index out of range". Can you help me to ignore these classes.
Expected result is

```
[OK, although it's been several weeks. When I got my grille back from the paint shop, I went to work on the],[Hello world]
```

sample website (https://www.f150forum.com/f118/fab-fours-black-steel-elite-bumper-adaptive-cruise-relocation-bracket-387234/)

Comment: I think your html is poorly formatted because there's no way to access "Hello world" because it is surrounded by closed tags

Comment: I have edited my html.

Comment: What do you actually want from that website?

Comment: @anonymous13 See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that might be feasible is to [`extract`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) out the div with class `panel alt2` and the `label` tag. The following code seems work on the site as well as your sample html.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.f150forum.com/f118/fab-fours-black-steel-elite-bumper-adaptive-cruise-relocation-bracket-387234/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
text = []
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="ism-true"):
    try:
        div.find('div', class_="panel alt2").extract()
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # sometimes there is no 'panel alt2'
    try:
        div.find('label').extract()
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # sometimes there is no 'Quote'
    text.append(div.text.strip())

print(text)
```

Output with your sample:

```
["OK, although it's been several weeks since I installed the \n\n    \n\nWhen I got my grille back from the paint shop, I went to work on the", 'Hello World.']
```

You can remove the *newline* characters if you don't require it

Comment: This brings: `["OK, although it's been several weeks since I installed the \n    \n    Quote:\n\n\n            Originally Posted by DeltaNu1142\n\nThe very first thing I did",
 "Quote:\n\n\n            Originally Posted by HCFX2013\n\nI must be the minority that absolutely can't .\n\nHello World."]` which is more than what OP asked

Comment: @JuanC Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I did not try it with the  html he posted here and went directly for the link.  I was answering specifically to this: `I want text which is only in post message class but not in "panel alt2" class. The position of class within "div id="post_message_" keeps changing. How can I ignore the text with in the panel alt2 class.`

Comment: @BittoBennichan It works fine when quote is in middle of the text but when the quote is in the beginning of the text it just ignore entire comment - Just like the comments in the link (https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/index2/)